# Redux store variables suddenly undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to add json objects to an array. `console.log(...)` doesn't return `undefined` but `[]`. However when I try to insert an object I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` exception.

**Store with reducer**

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch(action.type) {

        // REST
            case 'RECEIVED_PRODUCTS':
                return Object.assign({}, ...state, {products: action.products});


        // KEYBOARD

            // SEARCHBAR
                case 'SEARCH_CHANGE':
                    return Object.assign({}, state, { searchWord: [...state.searchWord, action.text] });
                case 'SEARCH_CHANGE_CORRECT':
                    return Object.assign({}, state, { searchWord: state.searchWord.slice(0, state.searchWord.length-1)});
                case 'SEARCH_CHANGE_SPACE':
                    return Object.assign({}, state, { searchWord: [...state.searchWord, ' ']});
                case 'SEARCH_CHANGE_DELETE':
                    return Object.assign({}, state, { searchWord: ''});

            // VIRTUAL KEYBOARD
                case 'TOGGLE_KEYBOARD':
                    return Object.assign({}, state, { toggleKeyboard: !state.toggleKeyboard});


        // BUTTONSGRID
            case 'PRODUCT_ADD':
                return Object.assign( {}, state, {basket: [...state.basket, action.product]}); 


        // BASKET
            case 'PRODUCT_REMOVE':
                var removedFromBasket = state.basket.filter(function(product) {return product !== action.product});
                return Object.assign( {}, state, {basket : removedFromBasket});
            case 'PRODUCT_SET_COUNT':
                break;

        default:
            return state;  
    } 
}
```

This is the component that renders a table with `this.props.basket`

**Basket**

```
class Basket extends React.Component {


    productClicked = (row) => {
        console.log(row.description);
      }

    removeProductFromBasket = (product) => {
        console.log("Removing product")
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ReactTable
                    data = {this.props.basket}
                    columns= {[
                        {
                            Header: "Name",
                            accessor: "description"
                        },
                        {
                            Header: "Preis",
                            id: "salesPrice",
                            width: 50,
                            accessor: p => p.salesPrice,
                        },
                        {
                            Header: "Anzahl",
                            id: 'purchasePrice',
                            accessor: "purchasePrice",
                            Cell:({row}) => (<Button onClick={() => this.productClicked(row)}>{row.purchasePrice} Stk.</Button>)
                        },
                    ]}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        basket: state.basket       
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return { 
        searchChanged: (data) => {
            let action = undefined;
            dispatch(action);
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Basket);
```

**`mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` in the Buttons component:**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        basket: state.basket,
        products: state.products
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return { 
        onButtonPress: (data) => {
            let action = { type: 'PRODUCT_ADD', product: data };
            dispatch(action);
        },
        getProducts : function() {
            dispatch(getProducts());
        }
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ButtonsGrid);
```

And finally the `initialState`

```
const initialState = {

    // KEYBOARD
    searchWord: '',
    toggleKeyboard: false,

    // BASKET
    basket: [],

    // PRODUCTS
    products: []
};
```

I tried adding manually an object and it's working - I copied the exact same json object I'm trying to add through `redux`.

I debugged the app in chrome and funnily everything except `products` is [undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNjyC.jpg).

`action.product` is btw the object that is assigned to the button I pushed.

[Here's](https://imgur.com/a/fOZq6) the stacktrace.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this the entire application? Are you sure you're not calling an action with `PRODUCT_SET_COUNT`? In that situation, the reducer would return undefined.

Additionally, `Object.assign({}, ...state, {products: action.products})` is suspicious. I suspect you meant to do `Object.assign({}, state, {products: action.products})`

Comment: It's a [PRODUCT_ADD](https://ibb.co/itrC0H) action. I am never calling `PRODUCT_SET_COUNT.

Comment: Okay I removed the spread from `Object.assign({}, ...state, {products: action.products})` and it works... It even fixed a UI issue where a component was disappearing when another loaded. I actually had `Object.assign({}, ...state, {products: action.products})` because somehow without the spread operator it wasn't working.

Comment: @Claim0013 `Object.assign` expects arguments that are objects and "...copies all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object." The spread operator yields key-value pairs, not objects `{...state}` would work in this case and is equivalent to `state`.